# ffmpeg stream of raw h264 frames over ssh channel

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

This is a C++ project. I have a remote server with an ip camera connected to the network. My cLient is connected to the server over a ssh channel. I want ffmpeg to stream raw h264 frames to the client to display a video on the application window. My problem is that ffmpeg only delivers one single frame to be displyed.

Here is my code:

```
retVal = ssh_channel_request_exec(channel,
    "ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://localhost:554/101 -c copy -f h264 pipe:");
if (retVal != SSH_OK) {
    sprintf_s(buffer, "Error: %s\n", ssh_get_error(session));
    SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETTEXT, 3, (LPARAM)buffer);
    return 0;
}

size_t memsize = 1024 * 100;
uint8_t* data = (uint8_t*)malloc(memsize);
size_t nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel, data, memsize, 0);
while (nbytes > 0) {
    DataParser(data, nbytes);
    nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel, data, sizeof(memsize), 0);
}
```

First ssh_channel_read function can read one frame into the data buffer. But the same function in the loop only reads 8 bytes of garbage. Can someone please explain what I have missed.

Comment: You seem to assume that one call to `ssh_channel_read` corresponds to exactly one frame. is `DataParser` capable of reconstructing frames from multiple reads? Also, what does this buy you over just forwarding the RT(S)P stream to the client?

Comment: The first frame that ffmpeg sends is 33kB. Packets this big never come with the RTP protocol from the camera so I guess ffmpeg sends frame by frame to the channel. After that, the channel only gets 8 bytes. DataParser decodes h264 into a bitmap image in memory which is then displayed in the app's window. DataParser works with data from other cameras where the data is sent over HTTP so that function works.

Comment: You are still assuming that one read equals one full frame. If buffering is enabled you light get multiple frames in one read. If it is not you may need to accumulate multiple reads to decode as a frame. You have a framing problem and it is trivially solved by protocols such as rt(s)p. Also, did you check whether those 8 bytes are just a "no delta to previous frame"?

Comment: The first frame displayed is flawless, absolutely OK. Buffering following read 8 bytes will not be a frame, just garbage. I ran the ffmpeg command from power shell and saved the output to a file. I ran the file in VLC and the video displayed flawlessly.

Comment: You _are_ aware that H264, as an advanced compression codec, is capable of referring to parts of earlier frames, right? Those 8 bytes of "garbage" might just be "render the previous frame again" since you are looking at the output of an IP camera... the video displaying "flawlessly" when rendered in a file makes perfect sense since the decoded can see the previous frame just fine.

Comment: I ran a similar ffmpeg command locally and I see P- and B-frames of 200-700 bytes for a still image. So much for that hypothesis. Now we return to the "one frame per read" fallacy. Does `DataParser` expect a complete packet or does it keep track of data from incomplete packets too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just spotted the typo: You pass `sizeof(memsize)` to `ssh_channel_read` in the loop. That is always 8. You meant to pass `memsize` instead.

Comment: Of course, you're right. I should have seen that myself. Yes DataParser handles only complete packages. Now I can continue to work with frame slices .Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.